# Passing datetime parameters using DateTime Picker to Text Query in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing

I am trying to learn how to use Reporting Services and have been working with a project that I have exporting what I want. I have enhanced it to use a variable that filters, and am trying to add a variable into the dataset query.

This is where i'm having trouble. Below is my query which works fine.

```
DECLARE @reqDateTime VARCHAR(16), @TSQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @reqDateTime = '2014-01-14'

SET @TSQL = 'select convert(datetime, ''<<date>>'') Timestamp, <<other Columns>> 
from openquery
(<<server>>, ''SELECT ...etc...'')
order by <<other Columns>>'

SET @TSQL = REPLACE(@TSQL, '<<date>>', @reqDateTime)

exec (@TSQL)
```

But when i change it to this and set the Parameters in properties I get an error.

Code:

```
DECLARE @reqDateTime VARCHAR(16), @TSQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @reqDateTime = @filterByDateTime

SET @TSQL = 'select convert(datetime, ''<<date>>'') Timestamp, <<other Columns>> 
from openquery
(<<server>>, ''SELECT ...etc...'')
order by <<other Columns>>'

SET @TSQL = REPLACE(@TSQL, '<<date>>', @reqDateTime)

exec (@TSQL)
```

Parameter Name: @filterByDateTime

Parameter Value: [@AsAt]

Very important is that I am passing a time to the DateTime as well, which is based off this dataset:

```
select dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, getdate()) - (datediff(mi, 0, getdate()) % 5), 0) [DefaultDateTime]
```

Which will return something like (the last 5 minute increment): 2014-01-14 17:25:00.000

When i am designing the query and the popup asks for a default value for @filterByDateTime I set it to '2014-01-14 05:25:00 PM' and the query runs and gets the row names.

When running the report in the builder though i get this message:

```
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
----------------------------
Query execution failed for dataset 'MainDataSet'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
----------------------------
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. It was due to the fact that the Oracle server that the query was being passed to through openquery wanted the date specified in it's format. This was solved with this change to the expresion for the parameter:

```
=year(Parameters!AsAt.Value) & "-" & Right("00" & Month(Parameters!AsAt.Value), 2) & "-" & Right("00" & Day(Parameters!AsAt.Value), 2) & " " & Right("00" & Hour(Parameters!AsAt.Value), 2) & ":" & Right("00" & Minute(Parameters!AsAt.Value), 2)
```